# How to check with Rules if users have a custom picture

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

I have a rule with this Events:
-After saving a new user account
-After updating an existing user account

In conditions, I try to put "Data value is empty" -> account: (I don't found "picture", "image" or any of this)

I have:
admin/config/people/accounts
user images [check]

1.- Any idea how I can check if the user has used a custom image?

2.- Another question, is better add these events or "before saving a user account"?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Check image with custom PHP code
    
      `$user = user_load($account->uid);
      $filename = $user->picture->filename;`